# Como criar botão no code behind do Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo onde baixo algumas umas imagens da internet quando o aplicativo é aberto.

Estou querendo, quando eu tiver estas imagens baixadas, criar um botão para cada imagem e colocar ela no background. Mas, como não sei quantas imagens vou baixar, não posso criar os botões no XML. Queria criar no java. Como faço isso?

Com a resposta do cicero funcionou, só estou com um problema a imagem ficou maior que a tela e está sendo cortada, tem como eu diminuir ela dentro do código ou só se tratar ela antes de colocar no código?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer das duas formas, tanto no XML como via código.

A vantagem de ser via XML é que você não escreve tanto no código.

ImageButton:

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imageButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    File file = new File("caminho para a imagem");
    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

    //Se quiser algum tamanho especifico
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        //aí você adiciona essa imagem onde quiser, num ViewGroup
        layoutPai.addView(imageButton);
```

Via XLM:

**Arquivo imagebutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton" />
```

No código:

```
 ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.imagebutton, null);
```

onde está `null` acima, você pode passar o pai, que será o `ViewGroup`

```
File file = new File("caminho para a imagem");
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
imageButton.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

//aí você adiciona essa imagem onde quiser, num ViewGroup
layoutPai.addView(imageButton);
```

Comment: obrigado vou tentar.

Comment: Cicero meu projeto deu um erro assim : Default Activity not found, mais só tenho uma Activity e ela não te nenhum erro.

Comment: @IlgnerOliveira fez a referencia da activity no `Manifest.xml` ?

Comment: sim. nem mexi 


<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Isso é pq existe algum erro no seu projeto. Veja se ao lado do Run lá em cima na IDE, o bonequinho do Android onde está o nome do seu projeto está com X vermelho de erro. Esse erro que vc viu ocorre quando existe algum erro no projeto ou mesmo no manifest mesmo, como o @Antony Alkimim mencionou acima.